# Does passport-jwt introduce any security advantages, over a "standard" JWT authentication?

Tags: javascript, express, jwt, passport.js, passport-jwt

I've reticently built some login and authentication functionality for our Express-based RESTful API.  The authentication middleware looks like that:

```
const Login = require('../services/UserLogin');
//Include this function in any route, to make it available for logged-in users only.
module.exports = async function requireAuth (req,res,next){
    const token = req.headers.token;
    if(!token){         
        return res.status(403).end();
    }
    const userObject = await Login.verifyLogin(token);
    if(userObject){     
        res.locals.id = userObject.id;//Append the user id, to be used during the request.
        res.locals.userObject = userObject;
        return next();
    }else{      
        res.sendStatus(403)
    }
}
```

The Login.verifyLogin function uses this, from a different module:

```
static verifyToken(token) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            jwt.verify(token, this.getSecretKey(), function (err, decoded) {
                if (err) {
                    resolve(false);
                } else {
                    resolve(decoded);
                }
            });
        })
    }
```

Simple enough. The question is, whether such functionality poses any "security risks", when compared to what passport-jwt does. I mean, from watching a tutorial about this module, all i saw is basically the same idea, just more flexible and configurable.

I will also note, that in Laravel, for instance, they "strongly recommend" not using their built-in token based API auth, and encourage us to use their implementation of Passport.

Can some one tell me what is the real advantage of using passport-jwt, besides the fancy options?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the APIs, but is your server using its private key to validate the JWT sent by the client (what does `this.getSecretKey()` return)? If so, what guarantees is that providing?

Comment: Yes i'm using a secret key, not available of course for the front-end. What do you mean by "what guarantees is that providing"?

Comment: The problem is that using JWT isn't inherently secure, depending on how you use it. It's just a means of passing signed or encrypted tokens around. The tokens could be created by the server or client, and be signed and/or encrypted using symmetric or public/private key algorithms. It's not clear from the code who created the token or what kind of algorithm is being used.

Comment: The token is being created by jsonwebtoken npm module.